# How to ignore case sensitivity in StartsWith for LINQ FindAll?

Tags: c#, linq, case-insensitive

I have the following code:

```
ContactList = ContactList.FindAll(p => p.DeptName.StartsWith(optAlpha.SelectedItem.Value)).ToList();
```

If `DeptName="test"` and `optAlpha.SelectedItem.Value="T"`, it doesn't work.

I tried with the following code, still doesn't work.

```
ContactList = ContactList.FindAll(p => p.DeptName.ToLower().StartsWith(optAlpha.SelectedItem.Value.ToLower())).ToList();
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Just use

```
StartsWith(optAlpha.SelectedItem.Value, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
```

and it will ignore the case during the default comparison.

Comment: @WinFXGuy, there is clearly a difference in the language cultures when that doesn't work. That wouldn't immediately be apparent, but leveraging the invariant culture is generally the best approach. Most times when you don't care about case, you too don't care about culture.

Answer (score 3):

No need to use `ToLower` you can just call an overload of starts with and pass it `StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` as the second arg (first being the string to compare). Here's the docs on string comparison options; [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparison(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparison%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)